# What is this slide bar in gnome?

Tags: gnome

What is the name of this slide bar in Ubuntu gnome?
I want to move it to the other side of my desktop but i don't know what to search !

Here is a screenshot displaying that slide bar:

[image: Slide bar shown in red circle]

Comment: Use a smaller screenshot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is called the **legacy-tray**, it is where running applications can put settings if they are not optimized for Gnome 3

I don't know about moving it to the right but [this extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1031/topicons/) moves it to the task bar and [this one](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/967/hide-legacy-tray/) removes it.

Comment: Perfect !
I used TopIcons and it saved me by moving it to the task bar.Thanks for the help.